# $ A_n $ =$[\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2}] $ be closed subsets find $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n $

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $ A_n  =\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2}] $, $n=1,2,3...$ be closed subsets of real line R. Then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n $ is

1. (1/2,1)
2. [1/2,1)
3. (1/2,1]
4. [1/2,1]

My attempt : think it could be [1/2,1) since $\lim \frac{n+1}{n+2}$=1 . I am not sureit is just a guess.any hints plz.

Comment: Consider the endpoints of that interval carefully, as these are the only distinctive aspects of the multiple choices you gave us.

Answer (score 6):

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{m}\left[\frac{n}{n+1}\,,\,\,\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right]=\left[\frac{1}{2}\,,\,\,\frac{m+1}{m+2}\right]$$

Take limit $m\rightarrow \infty$ you get
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\left[\frac{1}{2}\,,\,\,1\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ is monotonically increasing, we have that for any $0\le x\lt1$,
$$
n=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{1-x}\right\rfloor\iff n\le\frac{x}{1-x}\lt n+1\iff\frac{n}{n+1}\le x\lt\frac{n+1}{n+2}
$$
Thus, for any $\frac12\le x\lt1$, if $n=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{1-x}\right\rfloor$, then $n\ge1$ and $x\in\left[\frac{n}{n+1},\frac{n+1}{n+2}\right]$.

Furthermore, note that for all $n\ge0$, $\frac{n+1}{n+2}\lt1$.